# Match an array with String value in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

In mongoose schema, I have a field with String type value.
e.g. `Name: {type: String, required: [true, 'Name is required']}`

Now If I am passing array of string (['John', 'Doe', 'Jenny']) to be searched for **Name** field. If any records matched name value from this array, I want to return that particular object.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) operator like this

```
db.SCHEMA.find( { Name: { $in: [ 'John', 'Doe', 'Jenny' ] } } )
```

Just keep in mind `$in` uses `OR` condition. 
Which means it performs a logical OR operation on an array of two or more expressions and selects the documents that satisfy at least one of the expressions.

Comment: Thanks @ShivamSood for your help. I will try this, and get back to you if I will face any issue. :)